# Pandas Parallel Coordinates Visualization

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
        var1      var2        var3        var4
    0.319192    0.171150    0.171150    0.025979
    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
    0.064174    0.412816    0.412816    0.123353
    0.169651    0.154202    0.154202    0.114456
    0.351844    0.128112    0.128112    0.142504
    0.110982    0.294123    0.294123    0.308963
```

I am trying to think of ways to visualize how each of these variables vary with each other - multivariable visualization.  What do you reckon would be the best way to do this?  With Parallel coordinates, like below?  I cann't seem to determine how to modify my dataframe to get a 'class column'.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!  [image]

Comment: like [sns.pairplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html)?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question and arguably not really a programming question. Typically if you want to get an overview of the correlations and distributions you would use a pairs plot, also known as a scatterplot matrix. See this article:

https://towardsdatascience.com/visualizing-data-with-pair-plots-in-python-f228cf529166